# SYMFONY5 + MySQL - COMMIT in mysql hangs whole application

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony

Im having an issue since couple of weeks. We have a live web app created on SF5 with MySQL (5.7.26). Recently we got reported about some issues, that application stops for 30 to 60 seconds. After big digging, we found that the requests are stucked on PHP app, to be more specific, in MYSQL queries. It happens randomly (we think), and we lost a lot of time trying to debug it, as it can come once in an hour. We found that the exact time which we are stuck on symfony is the time for couple of 'COMMIT's. (screen below)

[SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAmWQ.png)

When they are getting ROLLBACK, the system is going back to normal.

How can we check what's the issue there and why is there rollback happening. During the test, we are doing the same thing like 200 times, and 201. is with the issue. It causes several other problem on Vue applicaton, like Vue sending 1 request several times, which is then hard to secure on backend, as all of the requests end on the exact same time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried activating slow query log, to see if that reveals which exact query is causing this? I dont know how large you application is, but manual commits might not be that common in the app, so maybe it could be possible to search the codebase for `->transactional(` and `->commit()` to be able to make a better guess of which code is causing the problem?

Comment: yes i did, but there is only COMMIT for that 30s query, its 3 to 5 times at the time.. i think im on the good way to solve it, i changed innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit to 0, and COMMITs are not showing up anymore.. i have to get more into the flag to see if it will not affect our system in some other way, but for now looking promising